# Typescript type of tuple member dependent on other

Tags: typescript

I want to create a function which accepts many pairs of objects and keys of those objects and have the compiler enforce that. I currently have written the following:

```
declare function foo(...params: [any, string][]): void;
```

Which allows me to write something like

```
foo([a, "propOfA"], [b, "propOfB"]);
```

However, it also allows me to write

```
foo([a, "propofB"], [b, "propOfA"]);
```

This makes sense because the type of the second value is simply `string`. Can I use `keyof` to restrict the second value of every tuple to be a key of the first value of the same tuple?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You can do it with a single generic function using inference from mapped tuples, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57100606/2887218)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in @ExplosionPills's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57100483/2887218) works if you only have one argument.  If you want to support multiple tuple-valued arguments, each of which constrains the second element to be a key of the first, you can do it like this:

```
declare function foo<A extends any[]>(
  ...params: { [I in keyof A]: [A[I], keyof A[I]] }
): void;
```

Here we are using [mapped tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to represent `params` as a function of the `A` array, and [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) allows us to infer `A` from the first element of each tuple argument.  Let's make sure it works:

```
const a = { a: 1 };
const b = { b: 2 };

// not allowed
foo([a, "b"]);
foo([b, "a"]);
foo([a, "a"], [b, "a"])

// okay
foo([a, "a"]);
foo([b, "b"]);
foo([a, "a"], [b, "b"]);
```

Looks good to me.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwB4BBeEADwxFWAGd4pUBPAbQF0A+ACgCh54AOmEAHWFAC2dAFzwA3vFYBJeFnwBrEMxyJ4JdrNYll7ADTxN23caXt28AL68AlLIBuOLMADcvXmDw6DEZ4AF55RlkARkdfANQg+AAjMIik2QAmWL8Aehz4VBxgqAgIHAB3EGBeREJuVihzACIkpvZnX1qceqTmqDaOmrqGvrbzVl74Jv723PycdShmIe6RqZnBrp7m1vbO4cb1scVJloHfIA)

Comment: This is a nice solution, and thank you for making me aware of this construct.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using generics:

`declare function foo<T>(...params: [T, keyof T][]): void;`

Now, the type T will be inferred from the first array element of the argument you pass in.

```
const a = { a: 1 }
const b = { b: 2 }

// not allowed
foo([a, 'b']);
foo([b, 'a']);

// okay
foo([a, 'a']);
foo([b, 'b']);
```

Note that if you use multiple arguments, e.g. `foo([a, 'a'], [b, 'b'])` `a` and `b` will have to be of the same type (or compatible types).

Comment: In case you care, it is possible to make it work for an arbitrary number of independent parameters; see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57100606/2887218).